# How to download navigator.getMediaStream audio blob on stop recording in .wav format in Firefox

Tags: firefox, blob, wav, audio-recording, navigator

I want to record an audio using `navigator.getMediaStream` and download it in .wav format but currently it gets downloaded in the '.ogx' format in Firefox browser.

I have tried by using `audio/wav` type in blob but still it's downloading in .ogx format instead of .wav format.

```
      const blobDataInWavFormat: Blob = new Blob([blobDataInWebaFormat], { type : 'audio/wav; codecs=0' });
      const anchor = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(anchor);
      anchor.style = 'display: none';
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      anchor.href = url;
      anchor.download = 'audio.wav';
      anchor.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```